# how to get latitude and longitude data from HDF files in matlab?

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude, hdf5

I have some MODIS data (MOD17A2) in HDF files. The data are all showing one same grid (1200*1200 pixels) for one year. I need to retrieve only one pixel data (my targeting point) for each HDF file and finally create one year time-series data for my targeting point. Now i can view the 1200*1200 matrix data in matlab and know the lat/long for 4 gridcorners and the gridcenter. How can i locate my targeting point(known lat/long) in the 1200*1200 matrix?

```
clear all; clc;
%Opening the HDF-EOS2 Grid File
FILE_NAME='MOD17A2.A2012273.h09v04.005.2013230033352.hdf';
file_id = hdfgd('open', FILE_NAME, 'rdonly');

%Reading Data from a Data Field
GRID_NAME='MOD_Grid_MOD17A2';
grid_id = hdfgd('attach', file_id, GRID_NAME);

DATAFIELD_NAME='Gpp_1km';

[data1, fail] = hdfgd('readfield', grid_id, DATAFIELD_NAME, [], [], []);

%Convert M-D data to 2-D data
data=data1;

%Convert the data to double type for plot
data=double(data);


% This file contains coordinate variables that will not properly plot. 
% To properly display the data, the latitude/longitude must be remapped.

[xdimsize, ydimsize, upleft, lowright, status] = hdfgd('gridinfo', grid_id);
%Reading attributes from the data field
SD_id = hdfsd('start',FILE_NAME, 'rdonly');
DATAFIELD_NAME='Gpp_1km';

sds_index = hdfsd('nametoindex', SD_id, DATAFIELD_NAME);

sds_id = hdfsd('select',SD_id, sds_index);

%Reading filledValue from the data field
fillvalue_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, '_FillValue');
[fillvalue, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, fillvalue_index);
%The _FillValue in the file contains value 32767 but the actual value
%observed from the data is 32766.
fillvalue = 32761:32767;

%Reading valid_range from the data field
valid_range_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'valid_range');
[valid_range, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, valid_range_index);

%Reading units from the data field
units_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'units');
[units, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, units_index);

%Reading scale_factor from the data field
scale_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'scale_factor');
[scale, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, scale_index);

%Reading add_offset from the data field
offset_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'add_offset');
[offset, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, offset_index);

% Reading long_name from the data field
long_name_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'long_name');
[long_name, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, long_name_index);

%Terminate access to the corresponding data set
hdfsd('endaccess', sds_id);
%Closing the File
hdfsd('end', SD_id);

%Replacing the filled value with NaN
for i=1:length(fillvalue)
data(data==fillvalue(i)) = NaN;
end
%Replacing the out of range values with NaN
data(data < valid_range(1)) = NaN;
data(data > valid_range(2)) = NaN;

%Multiplying scale and adding offset, the equation is scale *(data-offset).
data = (data-offset) * scale*1000;
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source file?

Comment: @Pursuit http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD17A2.005/2012.09.29/

Answer (score 1):

(Update: 20222-11-11)
The latest MATLAB can calculate and return lat/lon from HDF-EOS files.

The solution below is for older versions of MATLAB.

---

You can use HDF-EOS2 dumper tool to generate lat/lon in ASCII text files first and read them back in MATLAB. The complete code of utilizing this technique is available at

http://hdfeos.org/zoo/LPDAAC/MOD17A2_PsnNet_1km.m

The above code used the following HDF-EOS2 dumper tool options to dump latitude and longitude from MOD17A2 in ASCII.

```
$eos2dump -c1 MOD17A2.A2007113.h11v09.005.2007136163924.hdf > lat_MOD17A2.A2007113.h11v09.005.2007136163924.output
$eos2dump -c2 MOD17A2.A2007113.h11v09.005.2007136163924.hdf > lon_MOD17A2.A2007113.h11v09.005.2007136163924.output
```

Then, you can check your location of interest from the plot below or search lat/lon value from the MATLAB array created by reading the ASCII files.

[image: Plot of the above MATLAB code]